# Angular 2/4 ,report generating with html content issue

Tags: jquery, angular, angular2-directives

I have a requirement to generate a report using `html` content, I am new to `angular` and I have tried following methods but couldn't able resolve the issue,

> Method 01

I designed `report with html` and put it in `component.html` and generate the report with `jquery window.open and write`.
with this method report generated successfully but could not able to bind the data because at the moment report loading `html and angular variables are rendered to html` :-(

> Method 02

then i got a idea to put `html` report into another component and show it in a `popup`. but I tried but i could not able to find a way to open component on `popup`

> Method 03

I moved report html to separate folder and tried to open with `jquery window.open`, but `angular routing` not giving access to `html` file :-(

basically i want to open my `html` report in a `popup (not model)` and bind the data on `popup loading`,

if anyone can help me to figure this out would be very much appreciate,
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you need to put your reporting logic inisde `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: actually there is no login, just wanna show some detail on report link click, but at the time I click on report link, variable are rendered as html,

Comment: did i say you can have it in the component after `viewInit`

Comment: but report html block is also within component.html file know? even thought i generate report inside ngAfterViewInit ,  variables values are not binding, those variables are already rendered